# Properties of a certain prime number.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be a nonzero integer and suppose $p$ is a prime number with property $p$|$(2n)^4$+$1$.

- How do I show that $2n$ mod $p$ is in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, and that it has order $8$ in this group?
- How do I show that $p \equiv 1$ mod 8?
- And how do I show that there exist infintely many prime numbers $\equiv$ 1 mod 8?

I have been trying to solve these questions numerous times, but still without any success. Any help would be nice!

Comment: Well the second and third parts both follow immediately from the first.

Comment: @Derek Holt: with all due respect and consideration, the second claim does follow quite immediately from the first, yet deriving the third requires a bit of an auxiliary reasoning (which might not be so immediate for someone still in course of familiarising himself with the basics).

Comment: Yes, maybe, but it is no more difficult than Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give a very succinct reply to your questions:

1. Let us agree to write $\overline{m}$ for the reduction modulo $p$ of arbitrary integer $m$. By your hypothesis we gather $\overline{2n}^4=-\overline{1}$ so if we further abbreviate $a=\overline{2n}$ taking squares in $a^4=-\overline{1}$ leads to $a^8=\overline{1}$. Hence, $a$ is invertible (of inverse $a^7$) and this same relation tells you that $a$ is of order a divisor of $8$; since these divisors are $1, 2, 4, 8$ yet the fourth power of $a$ is not yet the unity (the number $(2n)^4+1$ being clearly odd, it follows that $p \neq 2$ and hence that $-\overline{1} \neq \overline{1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$), you can draw your conclusion.
2. The multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$ is finite of order $p-1$ and contains an element of order $8$ by (1); the conclusion follows from Lagrange's theorem (the order of any subgroup divides the order of the ambient group).
3. The previous argumentation tells us that any prime divisor of a number of the form $(2n)^4+1$ is $1$ modulo $8$. Let us argue by contradiction in assuming that the set of all (positive) primes that are $1$ modulo $8$ -- call it $P$--were finite; consider then 
   $$r=\prod_{p \in P} p \neq 0$$

and the number $m=(2r)^4+1$. As $m \geqslant 2$, it must have a (positive) prime divisor $q$ which will necessarily be an element of $P$; however, this would entail $q|r$ and thus $q|1$, a contradiction.